Store each line as a variable from list.txt file and pass it in loop to jenkins stage in jenkinsfile
10 lines in a UrlList.txt (basically list of docker image url's)
I now want to read the UrlList.txt file and pass each line as a value to a command in stage (e.g., UrlValue="$url") in loop like execute the stage for each line until last line.
Below is a sample code:
  stage('Extracting Image url'){
     steps {
       script {
           sh "sh extract_imageurl.sh"
           sh "cat images.txt"
       }
     }
   }
   
   stage('ImageScan'){
        steps {
            script {
                    prismaCloudScanImage ca: '',
                    cert: '',
                    dockerAddress: 'unix:///var/run/docker.sock',
                    image: ${url},
                    key: '',
                    logLevel: 'info',
                    podmanPath: '',
                    project: '',
                    resultsFile: 'scan-results.json',
                    ignoreImageBuildTime:true
                    Publish resultsFilePattern: 'scan-results.json'
                }
              }
            }
        }
   }

So I want to pass each docker image URL from images.txt as a value to image:
Not sure how to define readFile line by line and pass each line to run the stage('ImageScan') in loop.
Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks
I am expecting to run the stage('ImageScan') for each url in images.txt
